# Multiple independent webpack bundles: chunks load not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've an environment composed by two independent projects that can be described as follows:

- two webpack bundles, generated from two different projects: the **IDE** and the **App**.
- They are both ReactJS based (although I don't think this matters).
- The IDE is webpack 2.x based while the App is older (still webpack 1.x)
- no explicit dependency from one bundle to the other (no "import")
- both bundles expose a global function to be inited.
- the IDE is using webpack CommonsChunkPlugin, but removing it isn't fixing the issue (as reported at [Webpack config for Code splitting not working for production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376355/webpack-config-for-code-splitting-not-working-for-production-build?rq=1)).

Both the IDE and the App must be used from a 3rd party JavaScript environment. It will call `window.initIDE` and `window.initApp` when needed.
There's no explicit dependency because IDE and App must still work if the other is missing, so JS inclusion in the page is something like:

```
<script src=".../app.js" />
<script src=".../ide.js" />
```

This environment worked normally for a long time. The IDE is based on [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) so it used chunks and code splitting from the beginning.

Recently we added JS chunks also in the App by using [react-loadable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loadable).

While both IDE and App works as expected when only one of them is used on the page, chunks are not loaded if we activate both App and IDE: the *last* library that is used is the one that will not load chunks, while the first works as expected.

Inspecting the network tab of the browser we see **no activity on loading chunks** of the second called lib at all.

Obviously we get errors: Tracebacks are similar for both IDE and App:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__
```

Inspecting `__webpack_require__`:

```js
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
```

While `modules` is an array of all modules available, there's no `modules[moduleId]` because `moduleId` refers to an invalid index (probably because it has not been loaded... but why?)

I always believed that webpack internal implementation was not globally exposed outside the bundle build, but somehow this does not seem true.

How can a bundle interfere with the other? Why chunks are not loaded?
Any suggestion on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you merge them into a single project? This way you may remove redundant code and optimize better.

Comment: As I said, the must keep a good level of independence. Especially the _App_, which is a small project that is included on different 3rd party pages (with no _IDE_ at all).

Comment: 1. could you share your config?
2. have you tried switching off dedupePlugin in case you have one?
3. Have you tried updating webpack to the latest minor versions on both setups, to make sure it's not a webpack issue, that's been already fixed?
4. Have you tried incrementally switching off plugins and loaders one by one in pursuit to isolate the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should configure [output.jsonpFunction](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputjsonpfunction) property for each bundle.

Comment: Thank you very much, you fixed my issue.
I'm really astonished but this default behavior... it's like that every webpack constructed bundle in the world can break other ones... I don't get with this is not handled automatically someway (or documented more clearly).

Comment: @LucaFabbri I don't really know, maybe there's some way to use common chunks across bundles, and that's why it is like that. But I agree, that interference of bundles is strange for default behaviour.